# Geting data from a TextFile in C#

Tags: c#, authentication, text-files

Hello guys I want to make a Log In Form with dates from a text file and here's my code and I don't know why it doesn't work and also it doesn't show me any errors :\

```
    {
        string UserToSearch = textBox10.Text;
        string PasswordToSearch = textBox11.Text;

        string[] readText = File.ReadAllLines("LogIn.txt");
        try
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < readText.Length; i++)
            {
                if (readText[i] == UserToSearch && readText[i + 1] == PasswordToSearch)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("You found it");
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

and in my LogIn.txt file is Horatiu pas1 and Ana pas2

any kind of help would be great. Thank you ^^

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"?

Comment: Are you saving the username and the password on the same line in the text file, or on two separate lines?

Comment: user names and passwords as plain text in a textfile.  what could *possibly* go wrong...

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils when I press the button it  doesn't do anything

Comment: @Tha'erAl-Ajlouni yes I have Horatiu pas1 and the next line Ana pas2

Comment: Then the password is not on the i + 1 position of the array but in the same line of the name. You need to split the line on the blank space and check on the two parts returned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have a format problem: if actual data looks like

```
  Horatiu pas1 
  Ana pas2
  ...
  MyLogin MyPassword
  User 123
  Me MyTopSecretPassword
  Scott Tiger
```

(please, notice that both login and password are in the *same line*) you have to `Split` each line. Another suggestion is to use *Linq* instead of loop:

```
  var found = File
    .ReadLines("LogIn.txt")
    .Select(line => line.Split(' '))
    .Any(items => items[0] == UserToSearch && items[1] == PasswordToSearch);

  if (found)
    MessageBox.Show("You found it");
```